# How to pass a paramater in the onclick event in React (Could not get the value)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, parameters

I could not get the expected value so guys please help me out guys
The code should run and each time when the button is clicked it should increment one time
and have an id but it shows me that in the render method product is not defined

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Counter extends Component {
    state = {
        count: 0
     
    }

    //constructor() {
    //    super();
    //    this.handleIncreement = this.handleIncreement.bind(this);
    //}

    handleIncreement = product => {
        console.log(product);
        this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1});
    }

    render() { 
        return (
            <div>
            
            <span className={this.handlebadgeClasses()}>{this.handleCounter()}</span>
            <button onClick={ () =>this.handleIncreement(product) } className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Increement</button>
            
            </div> 
          );
    }

    handlebadgeClasses() {
        let classes = "badge m-2  badge-";
        classes += this.state.count === 0 ? "warning" : "primary";
        return classes;
    }

    handleCounter(){
        const {count} = this.state;
        return count === 0 ? 'Zero' : count;
    }
}
 
export default Counter;
```

Comment: Where do you declare the product? Put more information

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I dont think i understand what you want to achieve, but if in this line

```js
<button onClick={ () =>this.handleIncreement(product) } className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Increement</button>
```

you just want to increase the count, just do this:

```js
<button 
  onClick={ () =>{
    this.setState(prev=>({count: prev.count +1}))
  } } 
  className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Increement</button>
```

Comment: Bro i need to make sure i have a id for each product

Comment: if so, where did you put that id of the product? i dont see you initialized it anywhere